# VS2015: Xamarin license file is invalid

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin with Visual Studio 2015. After a recent upgrade of the Xamarin plugin, I'm getting an error the first time I try to "Clean Solution" or "Build Solution" after launching Visual Studio:

```
The Xamarin license file is invalid and could not be recovered. You will still be able to access the Xamarin features that are included in Visual Studio Professional.
```

The error dialog offers a single option: "Use Visual Studio Professional". If I choose that option, I can re-try whatever operation I was using and it will work fine, and continue to work fine until I exit and re-launch Visual Studio.

I have found some [older threads](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/64297/the-xamarin-license-file-is-invalid-and-could-not-be-recovered) where people mention what seem like similar problems, but the solutions refer to using Tools->Xamarin Account, which does not appear anywhere in my Visual Studio "Tools" menu.

Specific versions in play:
   Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
   Xamarin 4.8.0.754
   Xamarin.Android 8.1.0.13

I have this same problem with a couple of different, unconnected solutions (one of which is using Xamarin.Android, another of which uses Xamarin.Forms).

Comment: Others are reporting the issue here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/130418/xamarin-license-detector.html

Comment: [Here you can see your Xamarin account](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/97295/how-do-i-sign-in-to-xamarin-account-with-visual-studio-community-2017-for-mac)